# how to show multiple marker in google map

Tags: php, google-maps

```
<title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
<style>

  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var markers=[{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}];

function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("peta"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, lat, lng;
    var json=JSON.parse( markers );

    for( var o in json ){

        lat = json[ o ].lat;
        lng=json[ o ].lng;
        name=json[ o ].name;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            name:name,
            map: map
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
            infowindow.setContent( this.name );
            infowindow.open( map, this );
        }.bind( marker ) );
    }
}
</script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=340460420535-q0avndibuoa0c4jf8fhuj3i9no651si5.apps.googleusercontent.com&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

map not show in page. please provide solution for show marker in google map.
I am trying to Display the marker in Google maps with link no map displayed for some address.
I even get the address on google maps and use that but it still does not work
the text entry boxes display RED also if you insert coordinates they display RED.
see uploaded Code.

Comment: <div id="map"></div>

Comment: Why you tag `php`? I don't see any PHP code here

Comment: i m get marker dynamic from mysql

Comment: var markers=[{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}];

Answer (score 0):

**1st issue**

`var makers` is not valid JSON format.

Replace

```
var markers=[{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}];
```

into

```
var markers= '{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}';
```

**2nd issue**

change ID of element in HTML or JAVASCRIPT, choice is yours. `document.getElementById` is mapped to `peta`

Change from `<div id="map"></div>` into `<div id="peta"></div>`

**3rd issue**

You key seems to be invalid. Update your key.

Comment: var markers=[{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}];

Comment: @ChetanGupta yes for multiple you can use `[]` but move them into single quotes like `'[{"name":"Apple Store","lat":"51.51277","lng":"-2.14308"}];'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add multiple marker by addMarker() method like below :

```
   addMarker({lat:42.4668,lng:-70.9495});
        addMarker({lat:42.8584,lng:-70.9300});

        //add marker function

        function addMarker(coords){
            var marker =new google.maps.Marker({
            position:coords,
            map:map,
            icon:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'

        });

         
            }
```